# Favorite / Ignored tags interface not working?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, ignored-tags, tag-watching

Since today, the interface to ignore or add tags to favorites is no longer working for me. When I click on the star once, it adds a strange tag to my favorites - something like `tagsNAME_OF_TAGsubscriber-info` with "NAME_OF_TAG" being the actual tag (see below).

If I click a second time, I would expect the tag to move to the "Ignored" tags but instead it fades out from the favorites then reappears again in the favorites. The only way to actual delete the tag is to click on the red cross.

Any idea what could be causing this?

**Before clicking on the star:**

[image]

**After clicking on the star:**

[image]

Comment: I've found the same to be true. Chrome 15.0.854.0 (even with a cold cache).

Comment: The JavaScript handler for the star is accidentally getting passed the URL used to load the tag menu instead of just the tag name itself, so it `POST`s to the wrong URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a change in the way the tag dropdown was implemented.  This is fixed in the next release.