# Tag quick-follow broken?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Favorite / Ignored tags interface not working?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102781/favorite-ignored-tags-interface-not-working)

When I hover over a tag on SO and click the star (to mark a tag as a favorite), the star does not illuminate and in my *Favorite Tags* list I see a tag appear that looks like [tagtagnamesubscriber-info](/questions/tagged/tagtagnamesubscriber-info) -- where TAGNAME is the name of the tag I selected.  This happens even with a cold cache.

- Browser: Chrome 15.0.849.0 dev-m
- OS: Windows 7 (x64)

Comment: @Laurent Thanks. I didn't catch that existing post when I searched before I posted this.  Voted to close.