# Unable to favorite or subscribe tag

Tags: support, bug, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Favorite / Ignored tags interface not working?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102781/favorite-ignored-tags-interface-not-working)

I'm new to stackoverflow. But the first thing I want - is to see some new question on interesting for me tags (php, js, jquery, c++, etc). But I simply can't. Here's request

```
> Request
> URL:http://stackoverflow.com/tags/%2Ftags%2Fphp%2Fsubscriber-info/favorite
> Request Method:POST Status 
> Code:404 Not Found Request Headersview
> source Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
> Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
> Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
> Connection:keep-alive Content-Length:53
> Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Cookie:__qca=P0-717884062-1312233472488;
> __utma=140029553.1365752495.1312233473.1313507586.1313643836.39;
> __utmb=140029553.19.10.1313643836; __utmc=140029553;
> __utmz=140029553.1313643836.39.59.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=swift%20mailer%20return%20codes;
> usr=t=N5nt0T3vEaB2&s=CqiKkqzRZEax Host:stackoverflow.com
> Origin:http://stackoverflow.com Referer:http://stackoverflow.com/tags
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8)
> AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1
> X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest Form Dataview URL encoded
> action:favorite fkey:1f23f311ae6b403da453c33ec07e3235 Response
> Headersview source Cache-Control:private Content-Length:12927
> Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8 Date:Thu, 18 Aug 2011 05:11:50
> GMT
```